# Easy Asynchronous Image Download UIImage View

Tags: ios, ios5, asynchronous, uiimageview

I have an app i am building it works fine but the image source i am using is from a website and when I switch back to my initial view it takes quite some time for it to load. My question  is would there be a way to get this done and have the speed be faster.
here is the code I use to pull my image source

```
////Loads UIImageView from URL
todaysWallpaper.image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.inkdryercreative.com/daily/archive/mondays/images/062-mondays-960x640-A.jpg"]]];
```

any help or a shove in the proper direction. Soon the image will change every time day as well so any help/thoughts on that would be of great appreciation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The probleme here is that `dataWithContentsOfURL:` is on the main thread, so it will block your UI when the image is downloaded.

You have to download it asynchronously. For that I personally use a great piece of code i found on the internet : [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage). It does exactly what you want.

Comment: Add all the files to your project. Then import the category "UIImageView+WebCache.h". After that, you can do [myImageView setImageWithURL:myURL];

Comment: Hello, just followed your advice, but that didn't work. It builds and run fine, but no image shows up. Am I missing something?

Comment: Yes It should. Are you sure your urls are good ? (by the way, when an url fails one time, it is saved and won't be fetched again, I deleted this feature in my sources)

Comment: If someone needs resizing/cropping capabilities, I integrated this library with UIImage+Resize library. Check it out in https://github.com/toptierlabs/ImageCacheResize

Answer (score 1):

wrap the UIImage creation in a block running asynchronously (code assumes ARC) which in turn calls your callback in the main thread

```
@implementation Foo
...
Foo* __weak weakSelf=self;
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData: [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:
                   [NSURL  URLWithString:@"http://www.inkdryercreative.com/..jpg"]]];
    dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(),^ {
        //run in main thread
       [weakSelf handleDelayedImage:image];
    });
});

-(void)handleDelayedImage:(UIImage*)image
{
   todaysWallpaper.image=image;
}
```

the weakSelf trick ensures that your Foo class is properly cleaned up even if the URL request is still running